# Having trouble restoring SQL Server database from a different version of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-restore

I have problem restoring database to my server. I started working on SQL Server 2012, then I encounter this error:

> No backupset selected to be restored.

[image: 2012]

I read some question related to my question they answer is I need to upgrade my SQL Server to make compatible. So I upgraded my SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2014, and after that, I tried to restore the `.bak` files again, now to SQL Server 2014. But still I encounter this error.

> No backupset selected to be restored

[image: 2014]

Comment: What version of sql server is the backup from? Have you tried to simply script it out? Or use ola script?

Comment: hi @scsimon the database came from other side . they use SQL server 2014 then i try to use first the 2012 version. but got problem. then i read other question related to my question. they said it must be same version so i upgrade to 2014. then still got problem for that

Comment: That is correct. Are you selecting the .bak in the device section? What options are you using on the option tab

Comment: Are you selecting the .bak in the device section? Yes Task->Restore->Database->Device-> Add the files -> selected backup media -> Error No backupset selected to be restored

Comment: Post an inalienable if the options screen

Comment: I use this . RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSQLFOLDER\MSSQL\Backup\xxxxx.bak'
GO
the error says VERIFY DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182758/discussion-between-devge-and-scsimon).

Comment: If you look at the screenshots you've posted, it would appear that in fact this `.bak` file doesn't really contain any backup sets to be restored..... can you make another backup from the original server and try again?

Comment: @marc_s yah. i ask them to give me other backup.. lets see if works